# Get series names from LineChart object

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, linechart, series

For example I created `Linechart` and added series this way:

```
LineChart lineChart = new LineChart();
XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
series1.getData().add("Name1", xValue1[], yValue1[]);
series2.getData().add("Name2", xValue2[], yValue2[]);
lineChart.getData().add(series1);
lineChart.getData().add(series2);
```

If after that I send lineChart to other class, how can I get series names (*Name1* and *Name2*) using lineChart object from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using :

```
for(XYChart.Series series : lineChart.getData()) {
    series.getName();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. They are different too: Series and Object.

Comment: `lineChart.getData()` will always return a Series. What do you mean they have different types?

Comment: [IDEA says that they are different](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59953797/sample.jpg) 

. baseChart is:
LineChart baseChart;

Comment: This error is because your LineChart doesn't have a type. You can declare `LineChart<String, Number> baseChart`  or whatever type you are using. You can also type caste your list by declaring `ObservableList<Series> list = lineChart.getData();` and running a loop over `list`.

Comment: Thank you very much.
Decision is:
ObservableList<XYChart.Series> lists = baseChart.getData();
        for (XYChart.Series list : lists)   {
            list.getName();
        }